# Flask socketio, how to create room per user?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating a notifications service, and need to store one user in one room to send him notification to all opened tabs.
How can I put user per room? I had authorization, where users had username, and how can I create room mb for username, and then send user notification to all users tabs, using `socketio.send(broadcast=True)`.

Here some Python code:

```py
@login_required
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    return render_template('test.html',username=current_user.username)

@socketio.on('message')
def message(data):
username = current_user.username
send(data, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on('join')
def join():
    """User joins a room"""
username = current_user.username
room_name = current_user.username + "room"
print('ROOM NAME',room_name)
room = room_name
join_room(room)
send(username + ' has entered the room.', room=room)
```

And here JavaScript code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    socket.on('connect', () => {
        socket.send("Iam connected");
        socket.emit('join', {});
    });

    socket.on('message',data => {
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        const br = document.createElement('br');
        p.innerHTML = data;
        document.querySelector('#display-message-section').append(p);
    });

    document.querySelector('#send_message').onclick = () => {
        socket.send(document.querySelector('#user_message').value);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in presentation of rooms in my mind. I changed Python code like this:

```py
@login_required
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
return render_template('test.html', username=current_user.username)
@socketio.on('message')
def on_message(data):
"""Broadcast messages"""

room = current_user.username + '`s room'
send(data, broadcast=True, room=room)

@socketio.on('join')
def on_join(data):
"""User joins a room"""

username = current_user.username
room = current_user.username + '`s room'
join_room(room)
send({"msg": username + " has joined the " + room}, room=room)

@socketio.on('leave')
def on_leave(data):
"""User leaves a room"""

username = current_user.username
room = current_user.username + '`s room'
leave_room(room)
send({"msg": username + " has left the room"}, room=room)
```

and JavaScript code like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // Connect to websocket
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    let room = "Lounge"
    joinRoom("Lounge");

    socket.on('connect', function () {
        socket.send("Iam connected");
        joinRoom(room);
    });

    socket.on('message',data => {
        console.log(data);
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        const br = document.createElement('br');
        p.innerHTML = data;
        document.querySelector('#display-message-section').append(p);
    });

    function joinRoom(room,username) {
        socket.emit('join', {});
    }

    document.querySelector('#send_message').onclick = () => {
        socket.send(document.querySelector('#user_message').value);
    }
})
```

And for me it works, I save room like username of current user + "'s room", and joining it after creation. And after following the link '/test' for new logged User new room will be created. Also I added `room=room` to `send()` (`send(data, broadcast=True, room=room)`), to point that data must be sent only in this room.